# Opened port unreachable from only one machine

Tags: linux-networking, port

I do not have a good knowledge of network but my I have a very annoying issue. We have our corporate Git server running on a cloud hosting. In can reach the web interface on 80 (redirect to 443) and 443. In can also log in the server via SSH on standard port.

But whenever I want to issue a git command on a custom port (say 5893) the command hangs and ends up timed out. `nmap` and `telnet` are not more successful to connect on that custom port. However the service is running well because my other colleagues don't have the same issue and I can connect from another server. Note also that, sometimes, it works great.

I am aware that this is a quite vague question but I would like to have some directions to solve that issue.

```
$ telnet our_git_server_ip 22
Trying our_git_server_ip...
Connected to our_git_server_ip.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
^C
Connection closed by foreign host.

$ nmap -p 5893 our_git_server_ip
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-07-27 08:25 CEST
Nmap scan report for our_git_server (our_git_server_ip)
Host is up (0.013s latency).

PORT      STATE    SERVICE
5893/tcp filtered unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.25 seconds

$ telnet our_git_server_ip 5893
Trying our_git_server_ip...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

*Edit*

On the server side, It seems that our custom port is only available trough Ipv6:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1385/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::5893                 :::*                    LISTEN      97181/out-git-server
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1385/sshd
```

Comment: That's not a valid port number. Use a valid port number instead.

Comment: It was just a random number picked out of my brain the one which is used is valid (because my colleagues don't have the issue, it works on their machine). I replaced it.